# Checking which options were passed to ./configure

Tags: package-management, makefile

Is it possible to find out which options of the ./configure script were used to create the Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `configure` is run, it creates a log file `config.log`.  Right at the top of the file it will list what arguments were passed to `configure`.